# android: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for com.android.internal.telephony.RILConstants$SimCardID , I need this class to fetch Both SIM's Data

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, dual-sim

I am not getting any exception on Samsung Galaxy Y Duos(Dual SIM Phone)...I am getting exception on Samsung Galaxy Grand(Dual SIM Phone) and Samsung S Duos(Dual SIM Phone)...Is there any different name for the class in Samsung Galaxy Grand(Dual SIM Phone) and Samsung S Duos(Dual SIM Phone)?